# Construction of a shift map

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and  $f:\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\to \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ be defined by $f(\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}})=\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, where $y_n=x_{n+1}$ for $-k\leq n<k$, $y_k=x_{-k}$ and for $|n|>k$, we have $y_n=x_n$.

I need to construct $f^m:\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\to \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Take $f^m(\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}})=\{z_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. I think that $z_n=x_n$ if $|n|>k$.

What can say about $z_n$ for $-k\leq n\leq k$?

Please help me to know it

Comment: Try $f^2$ first.

Comment: @amsmath, I did it, in my research, I need to construct action $\varphi:N\times \{0,1\}^N\to \{0, 1\}^N$ defined by $\varphi(m, \{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty)=f^m(\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty)$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof, In my question, is it true that  if $m+n=kt+l$, then $z_n=x_l$?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof, Sorry, I change my question.

Comment: Yes, I saw. How many does one have to apply the map in order to get the original sequence? Hint: this is exactly the amount of numbers which get moved around each time.